# How to provide Google Maps API key with php and curl

Tags: php, curl, maps, key

I am trying to develop a small client to geocode the address and display it on the map. It all works fine, but I wanted to provide the api key so I can check the number of requests. I am using curl and php.

Here is the code:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=GIVEN_ADDRESS&key=API_KEY';

$client = curl_init();
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($client);
//$http_status = curl_getinfo($client, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($client);
```

When I try this i get request denied from google.

any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what is the HTTP response (including headers)?

Comment: The http response code is 200..

Comment: You're saying that the geocode response is REQUEST_DENIED?  http://goo.gl/8g4Qg  - Are you using a valid key from code.google.com/apis/console ?

Comment: The http response code is 200 what means the connection has been successful. In the json output I am getting back the status of requested_denied. If I dont supply the api key it works ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please provide full URL of request or use this one for test http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=USA (works for me)

Comment: This link will work, I am looking at passing the key value for the api

Comment: As I see on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ - API key not used here. So probably they havent implemented this feature yet.